# MongoDB aggregation for finding an index of array nested object with $gt condition

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am trying to get the positional index of an array element (to push more elements at `$position`). I'm specifically targeting a single document (say, `id=x`)

Simplified document:

```
{
id:"x",
samples:[{"timestamp":123},{"timestamp":234},{"timestamp":345}}
}
```

Aggregation pipeline:

```
collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"id": "x"}},
                      {"$project": {"matchedIndex": {"$indexOfArray": ["$samples.timestamp", 234]}}}])
```

This works to return `matchedIndex=1` .
Now I would like to find the index of `'samples'` where timestamp is greater than say `235`, which should return `'2'`

I have tried combinations of:

```
collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"UUID": "5fd41e35-5e49-O977-t091-6f228bc65e37"}},
                      {"$project": {"matchedIndex": 
                                     {"$indexOfArray": ["$samples.timestamp", 
                                       {"$gt": ["$$timestamp", 235]}]}}}])
```

I understand this wont work, I'm just not sure how to go about it.

The purpose is to insert many elements between timestamps. Maybe there is a better way entirely to do this. Thanks

Comment: What is your mongoDB version?

Comment: You can use `$reduce` to get this index, but please provide example of the items you want to insert and the requested result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `"$samples.timestamp"` as first argument you can use [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) there to transform it into an array of `true` and `false` values depending on your condition, try:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "matchedIndex": {
            "$indexOfArray": [
                { $map: { input: "$samples.timestamp", in: { $gte: [ "$$this", 235 ] } } },
                true
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XQjf2oEShsY)

Comment: Works 100%! Thank you!